# Scala dependency in Java project - versioning

Tags: java, scala, versioning

It is well known that whenever Scala libraries are created, it's a good practice to add support for multiple Scala versions within the libraries. The reason behind it is the binary incompatibility that can happen between two different Scala versions.

But what happens in the following case: I have a library written in Java only which has dependencies of external Scala projects. Should my Java project version also include the Scala version? I mean: should I run different builds for different Scala versions of the dependencies?

Comment: Yes, if this library will be used by other Java (or Scala) library which depends on different Scala version.

Comment: Not a good situation to be in. If you are targeting Java users, you can probably dictate the Scala version they should use (they won't care. Unless they have another Scala dependency...).  For Scala users, they'd prefer your library to be in Scala in the first place. I'd hold off on cross-compilation until one of my users actually asks for it. Quite a hassle otherwise.

Comment: For a real-life example see Lagom. That is implemented in Scala, but provides a Java API (for a while, that was even the *only* API). And they do in fact distribute separate builds (of the Java libraries) for the different Scala versions.